# Javascript scoring app hooked up to Cobol

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks, cobol

I have a large Cobol system with huge amounts of data - the data can be output as either xml or json. I'm in early stages of looking at creating an in-browser app to hook into these stats and present them to the user.

So I guess I'm looking for easy templating for views, scalability (current system hits 1 million a week), user management (logins, security etc).

I think js is the way to go but would like any thoughts on this.

I'm currently looking at Ember, Angular and poss Backbone/Marionette but defer to those with more experience.

Comment: It might not be appropriate to needs, but;  Embed a javascript engine in COBOL, play directly from there.  http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#can-opencobol-use-javascript libsoup sample at http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#libsoup-http-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can go the full Javascript way: [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/) with a framework like [**Express**](http://expressjs.com/) on the server side, **Angular** on the browser side, [**Socket.io**](http://socket.io/) for linking the two and a good charting library like [**Rickshaw**](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/), [**Highcharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/) or [**jqPlot**](http://www.jqplot.com/).

If you need a good book for Node.js have a lookt at ["**Smashing Node.js**"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119962595).